# Ant design - custom spacing between menu item

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, antd

I have a `Menu` Component

[image]

As you can see, there are two problems on the Menu Component

```
1. The padding-left and padding-right(red arrows) are not the same
2. The spacing between MenuItem(blue arrows) is not the same.
```

How can I update the styles to fix above problems?

demo.js

```
import React from "react";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Menu } from "antd";
import {
  MailOutlined,
  AppstoreOutlined,
  SettingOutlined
} from "@ant-design/icons";

const App = () => (
  <Menu
    mode="horizontal"
    defaultSelectedKeys={["mail"]}
    style={{ border: "1px solid grey", justifyContent: "space-between" }}
  >
    <Menu.Item key="mail" icon={<MailOutlined />}>
      Navigation One
    </Menu.Item>
    <Menu.SubMenu
      key="SubMenu"
      title="Navigation Two - Submenu"
      icon={<SettingOutlined />}
    >
      <Menu.Item key="two" icon={<AppstoreOutlined />}>
        Navigation Two
      </Menu.Item>
      <Menu.Item key="three" icon={<AppstoreOutlined />}>
        Navigation Three
      </Menu.Item>
      <Menu.ItemGroup title="Item Group">
        <Menu.Item key="four" icon={<AppstoreOutlined />}>
          Navigation Four
        </Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item key="five" icon={<AppstoreOutlined />}>
          Navigation Five
        </Menu.Item>
      </Menu.ItemGroup>
    </Menu.SubMenu>
    <Menu.Item key="mail" icon={<MailOutlined />}>
      Navigation Six
    </Menu.Item>
  </Menu>
);

export default App;
```

CodeSandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-usage-deprecated-syntactic-sugar-antd-4-22-4-forked-m4p6vh

Answer (score 0):

you can put all menu options in one `nav` tag, and add `menubar` class to it.

**CSS**

```css
.menubar {
  /*current style properties + */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Can you update the Codesandbox? thanks

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be, that you should use Flex for aligning the UI. Flex will work in any size of screen size. And moreover coming to your problem, it can be solved by the below example

```
.yourClassName{
    display:flex;
    justify-content:'space-evenly'
 };
```

Space evenly will add space to all elements in the class regardless of their size

Comment: I tried but it still looks like uneven

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want to spread it across the entire width but a nice solution is to put it between `<Space></Space>` (have a look here: https://ant.design/components/space/):

```
<Space>
  <Menu
    mode="horizontal"
    defaultSelectedKeys={["mail"]}
    style={{ border: "1px solid grey", justifyContent: "space-between" }}
  >
    <Menu.Item key="mail" icon={<MailOutlined />}>
      Navigation One
    </Menu.Item>
    <Menu.SubMenu
      key="SubMenu"
      title="Navigation Two - Submenu"
      icon={<SettingOutlined />}
    >
      <Menu.Item key="two" icon={<AppstoreOutlined />}>
        Navigation Two
      </Menu.Item>
      <Menu.Item key="three" icon={<AppstoreOutlined />}>
        Navigation Three
      </Menu.Item>
      <Menu.ItemGroup title="Item Group">
        <Menu.Item key="four" icon={<AppstoreOutlined />}>
          Navigation Four
        </Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item key="five" icon={<AppstoreOutlined />}>
          Navigation Five
        </Menu.Item>
      </Menu.ItemGroup>
    </Menu.SubMenu>
    <Menu.Item key="mail" icon={<MailOutlined />}>
      Navigation Six
    </Menu.Item>
  </Menu>
</Space>
```